# Magento 2 Custom Filters

Tags: magento2, filter, query

Dear Magento 2 developers,

I am currently new in the Magento 2 development, now I struggle about how to make custom Product filter on the sidebar, like the picture below.

[image]

My new brand column in Product:

[image]

Anyone know how to make custom filter on Magento sidebare?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer for that, it's called navigation-layered-filterable and could be found on this https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/catalog/navigation-layered-filterable-attributes.html